# Searching in an array and case sensitivity java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am trying to do a search feature in an array but I want to make the program as user friendly as possible so I want to include the code so that no matter what the user types in the textfield it will work so if there is a capital letter in the array but not in the textfield it will still work. so far i have this:

```
if (e.getSource() == search)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (searching.getText().equals(occupant[i]))
        {
            selectedApartment = i;
        }
    }
}
```

But not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I think you want `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pbabcdefp mentioned, you could use

```
if(searching.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(occupant[i]))
    selectedApartment = i;
```

You could also use the .toLowerCase function
where you set the input var like this

```
String lowercase = input.toLowerCase();
```